# Azkar and duas that raise status/ranks of a person in jannah

Tags: hadith

Please mention all of those azkar and duas in all hadiths that raise the status/ranks of a person in jannah like in the hadiths like whoever says this will be increased x many times in status in jannah and other azkar that does the same.Please email me.This my email: hamzazahidtu@gmail.com